# Azure Data Factory - Data flow activity changing file names

Tags: azure, filenames, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am running a data flow activity using Azure Data Factory. 
Source data source - Azure bolb
Destination data source - Azure Data Lake Gen 2

For Eg. I have a file named **"test_123.csv"** in Azure blob. When I create a data flow activity to filter some data and copy to Data Lake it is changing the file name to **"part-00.csv"** in Data Lake.

**I want to keep my original filename?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that , please look at the screenshot below . Please do let me know how it goes .[image]